# Unload data from snowflake into Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to unload data from a snowflake table into a Postgres database. Snowflake documentation does not show an unload option in a relational database.

Is there a way to unload the data from snowflake to Postgres currently.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake only has connectivity to *cloud storage*.  It can't connect to any other database directly.

If the table is small to medium size, you can use the Snowflake Web GUI:

1. Query the data: `SELECT * FROM my_table;`
2. Press the download button in the **Results** pane (next to the `Copy` button) and export as TSV or CSV
3. Import the file into Postgress (I don't know the details of this step)